# CSS color code for iOS Scroll View Textured Background Color

Tags: ios, css, background-color

Does anyone know the CSS color code? I want to use the same color for my web page. Thanks!

Comment: The definition of `texture` is something with more than one color.

Comment: Hex? RGB? and what color are you looking for? i.e red

Comment: Take a screenshot of it on your phone -> email or upload onto your computer -> open photoshop or even paint? -> find color code.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble loooooooooooooool =D

Comment: I did use the snapshot and then use PS to sample the code, but it gave me different code, like '#c1c1c6', '#c1c1c5', '#c1c1c0', all looking close to the texture color. Maybe, the texture color is indeed mixed with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll View Textured Background Color is kCGColorSpaceModelPattern i.e it is a pattern.
i had to use this color in my UIWebView page text color, so i converted this into color code like this

```
UIColor *color =[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
```

which returned me value (1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000) which is a clear color.

I used alternate color that was some form of Gray color and  resembled to scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor.
Color code for that color is

```
rgb(77,77,77)
```

You can use it,it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Native xCode colorPicker gives me next
rgb(111, 113, 121)
hex 6F7179